# How to display json with multiple dimensional array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, insomnia

[TypeScriptArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdkst.png)

Greetings. I have a problem with the array. I don't know how to display multiple dimensional arrays. This is the picture of my code on the left side and on right, I have JSON that I must display in Insomnia for the test. You can see

```
"lineups": {
                   "home_team": {
                       "starting_lineups": [
                           {
                               "player": "Asghar A. (C)",
                               "player_country": "Afghanistan"
                           },
....
```

I must display all the players and countries. All lines work well but for player and player_country, when I display, program print "undefined".

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: Code in text form is easier to read as link to the picture

Answer (score 0):

`starting_lineups` is array:

If you want to to use `player_country` from first array item:

```js
hometeam.lineups.home_team.starting_lineups[0].player_country
```